# Skycons Only Showing For Last Array Item

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm pulling data from the Darksky API and from the return data I get an array called daily; which gives me the daily weather for the coming week.

What I'm trying to do is loop through the array and dynamically add the info to the body.

When looping through I add a uuid to each canvas element and then use Skycons
skycons.add(id, day.icon); skycons.play(); forEach element using the uuid.

The problem is that when my program runs it only displays the icon on the last array item element.

```
const skycons = new Skycons({"color": "black"});
    class UI {
        constructor() {
            this.output = document.getElementById('output');
            this.iconOne = document.getElementById('icon1');
            this.spinner = document.getElementById('spinner');
        }

        paintUI(weather) {
            displaySpinner();
            setTimeout(() => {
                removeSpinner();
                this.output.innerHTML = '';
                const dailyWeatherData = weather.weatherData.daily.data;
                dailyWeatherData.forEach((day) => {
                let id = uuidv4();
                  this.output.innerHTML += `
                  <div class="animated fadeIn delay-500ms card">
                    <canvas id="${id}" height="128" width="128"></canvas>
                    <h3>${moment.unix(day.time).format("MMM DD, YY")}</h3>
                    <p>${day.summary}</p>
                  </div>
                  `
                  skycons.add(id, day.icon);
                  skycons.play();
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    function displaySpinner() {
        this.spinner.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
    }

    function removeSpinner() {
        this.spinner.classList.add('animated', 'fadeOut', 'delay-500ms');
        this.spinner.remove();
    }
```

Comment: Can you get a live version up perhaps on a stackoverflow code snippet or codepen?  I have a feeling this is an issue with how you are scoping your variables, or lack of. You made need a closure to save the reference to the variable.

Comment: https://problem-weather.netlify.com/

Comment: The UI isn't even close to done, but if you scroll down you'll see how the icon is showing for the last one.